# I can't sprint in FIFA 16?

Tags: fifa-16

I recently download FIFA 16 on my new MSI gaming laptop. There is no problem with the performance.

However, I noticed that the keyboard configurations for various actions (pass, shoot, lob etc.) keep changing even after I save them in a profile!

For example,
I keep <kbd>E</kbd>as *sprint* and <kbd>C</kbd> as *change player*. I change defending to "Tactical Defending" and I save it in profile A and return to the main menu. If I go back and check the control settings, it has all changed back to original.

Sometimes it sticks to the changed configuration and sometimes it doesn't. I also connect the controller to play 2 player matches.

What's the solution to this problem?

Comment: We probably need a lot more information. What PC specs? What operating system? What version/patch?

Comment: A lot of information I've heard about this seems to think that it has to do with [server load in multiplayer matches](http://fifaforums.easports.com/en/discussion/6451/players-not-sprinting). Can you play an offline game and see if the sprinting issue is the same?

Comment: I found out that the keyboard and controller seems to be somehow intertwined. Whatever defence (tactical or legacy) that I use for one seems to be the option for the other too. I can't keep legacy for keyboard and tactical for controller (and vice versa).